# Bound Services in MVVM pattern

Tags: android, android-service, android-livedata, android-architecture-components, android-mvvm

I'm working on an Android app (in Java) and trying to use Google's [recommended application architecture](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/guide), but I can't seem to figure out where services fit in to this architecture. I've done a lot of looking online and there is no clear consensus on how this should be done.

For context, my application communicates with a BLE device. I've created `BLEService` which extends `Service` that establishes the connection with the device, and provides methods send data to the device. The device can also send data back (and thus needs to notify the app when data is received).

My question is, where should the `ServiceConnection` reside, and how should it be stopped/started? From my research, there are a couple options that each have their pros and cons.

1. The Service is started/stopped in the Activity, the Activity observes events from Service. The Activity forwards the events to the ViewModel for processing. This pattern keeps all of the Android components together, but gives more responsibility to the View than I believe it should. The View should only be responsible for handling the UI.
2. The Service is stopped/started in the ViewModel (perhaps by extending `AndroidViewModel`). The ViewModel observes events from the Service and processes the events. This pattern is nice because the ViewModel is handling the business logic, however if Service implements its events via `LiveData`, Google states that the ViewModel *must not* observe `LiveData`. Another option is for the Service to implement events via something like `EventBus`, but there are a lot of people against using `EventBus` because it is easy to abuse. I have also heard that `ViewModel` should not have any Android-specific code in it for testing purposes.
3. The Service exists in some sort of Repository/Model. The ViewModel forwards its sends and observes events from the Repository/Model. This solution is nice because interfacing with a Bluetooth device does seem like it fits the intended purpose of what a Model is. However, it suffers the same issue that the ViewModel must not observe LiveData. I have seen [Transformations.switchMap](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/arch/lifecycle/Transformations) suggested in this case, which causes a LiveData in the ViewModel to be updated in response to a change in a LiveData from the repository. I'm not totally clear on using this strategy, or how it would function in my specific use-case. There's also the issue that the repository needs access to `Context`, and I have heard it's bad practice to hold on to an instance of `Context`. Furthermore, I have also read that a Repository should not hold on to callbacks from the ViewModel.

I'm sure there's no perfect solution, but if someone could point me in a direction of best practices, particuarly in my use-case, that would be immensely helpful.

Comment: `I have also heard that ViewModel should not have any Android-specific code in it for testing purposes` well, you ignored that the moment you suggested using AndroidViewModel :)